# ASP.Net Core 5 Print Div Vertical Alignment Problem

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, printing

I have tried various alignment settings, but nothing is making a difference. Please have a look at the far right column in the image below and notice that the price is shifted down compared with the columns to the left.

Note that this is the print preview

[image: Print Preview]

This is what the same table looks like on the web page when not printing.
[image: Web Page View of Table]

You can see that in the web page, I have set the margin for the last column to `mt-0`.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">        
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="printDiv()">Print</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="PrintDiv">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
        <div class="row d-flex">
            <div class="col-8">
                <p>
                    <h2>@ViewBag.FullName</h2>
                    <h4>Order History</h4>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col me-1">
                <img src="@(Configuration.GetValue<string>("StorageContainerURL"))/store-logo.png" )
                     class="img-fluid " style="max-height:75px;width:auto" alt="Alternate Text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Order ID</th>
                    <th>Items</th>
                    <th>Total</th>                    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var order in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="align-middle">@order.OrderDate.ToLocalTime().ToShortDateString()</td>
                        <td class="align-middle">@order.Id</td>
                        <td class="align-middle">
                            <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                                @foreach (var item in order.OrderItems)
                                {
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                                            <span class="badge bg-success">@item.Amount</span> [@item.Price.ToString("c")] - @item.Product.Name
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                        <td class="mt-0">@order.OrderItems.Select(m => m.Product.Price * m.Amount).Sum().ToString("c")</td>
                        
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{ 

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function printDiv() {
            var divContents = document.getElementById("PrintDiv").innerHTML;
            var a = window.open('', '', 'height=500, width=500');
            a.document.write('<html>');
            a.document.write('<body > <br>');
            a.document.write(divContents);
            a.document.write('</body></html>');
            a.document.close();
            a.print();
        }
    </script>

}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to make `Total` column align properly with the other columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem shortly after I posted the question. I realized that the Printed Version of the page would not recognize the `Bootstrap` classes. So instead, I changed all columns to use `inline styles` for alignment.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var order in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:text-top">@order.OrderDate.ToLocalTime().ToShortDateString()</td>
            <td style="vertical-align:text-top">@order.Id</td>
            <td style="vertical-align:text-top">
                <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                    @foreach (var item in order.OrderItems)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                                <span class="badge bg-success">@item.Amount</span> [@item.Price.ToString("c")] - @item.Product.Name
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:text-top">@order.OrderItems.Select(m => m.Product.Price * m.Amount).Sum().ToString("c")</td>
            
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```